# Class method returns null value

Tags: java, class, null

I have written this code which calculates the coordinate points for each value.

```
nodeGenerator nG=new nodeGenerator(Permutation_S,WIDE,HIGH);
         nodes_permutation nP=new nodes_permutation();
         for(int i=0;i<Permutation_S.size();i++)
        {
             for(int j=0;j<Permutation_S.get(i).size();j++)
             {
                 Node.selectNone(nodes);
                 Point p = nP.get_coordinates((Integer) Permutation_S.get(i).get(j));

                 Color color = Color.blue;
                 Node n = new Node(p, radius, color, kind);
                 n.setSelected(true);
                 nodes.add(n);
                 repaint();
             }
        }
```

**nodeGenerator Class**

```
public class nodeGenerator {


    static ArrayList <List> Permutation= new ArrayList <List> ();
    int x,y;
    int width,height;
    int strt_x_l,strt_y_l;
    int strt_x_r,strt_y_r;
    public nodeGenerator(ArrayList <List> list,int w, int h)
    {
        this.Permutation=list;
        this.width=w;
        this.height=h;
        this.strt_x_l=this.width/2-250;
        this.strt_y_l=100;
        this.strt_x_r=this.width/2+250;
        this.strt_y_r=50;

        allocate_Coordinates();
    }

    public void allocate_Coordinates()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<Permutation.size();i++)
        {
            if(Permutation.get(i).size()>1)
            {/*if we have 4 points*/
                if(i%2==0)
                {
                new nodes_permutation(new Point(this.strt_x_l, this.strt_y_l),(Integer) Permutation.get(i).get(0));
                new nodes_permutation(new Point(this.strt_x_l-50, this.strt_y_l+50),(Integer) Permutation.get(i).get(1));
                new nodes_permutation(new Point(this.strt_x_l, this.strt_y_l+100),(Integer) Permutation.get(i).get(2));
                new nodes_permutation(new Point(this.strt_x_l+50, this.strt_y_l),(Integer) Permutation.get(i).get(3));

                /*increment position*/
                strt_y_l+=200;
                }
                else
                {
                    new nodes_permutation(new Point(this.strt_x_r, this.strt_y_r),(Integer) Permutation.get(i).get(0));
                    new nodes_permutation(new Point(this.strt_x_r-50, this.strt_y_r+50),(Integer) Permutation.get(i).get(1));
                    new nodes_permutation(new Point(this.strt_x_r, this.strt_y_r+100),(Integer) Permutation.get(i).get(2));
                    new nodes_permutation(new Point(this.strt_x_r+50, this.strt_y_r),(Integer) Permutation.get(i).get(3));
                    strt_y_r+=200;
                }

            }
            else
            {/*for static points*/

            }
        }
    }
}
```

And nodes_permutation class

```
public class nodes_permutation {

    int node_value;
    Point node_loc;
    String node_label;

    public nodes_permutation(Point p,int n_v)
    {
        this.node_loc=p;
        this.node_value=n_v;
        if(n_v==-1)
        {
            this.node_label="inf";
        }
        else
        {
            this.node_label=Integer.toString(n_v);
        }
    }

    public nodes_permutation() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Point get_coordinates(int n_v)
    {
        return this.node_loc;
    }


}
```

The problem is **Point p = nP.get_coordinates((Integer) Permutation_S.get(i).get(j));**, this line return null value. And i am unable to figure out the reason.

Comment: What's the point of the `int n_v` argument of `public Point get_coordinates(int n_v)` if you never use it?

Comment: When you have this kind of problem, you should consider debugging and/or logging.

Comment: What exactly is Permutation_S

Comment: @MI have debugged. And found this problem

Comment: @Aigloun static ArrayList <List> Permutation_S= new ArrayList <List> ();

Comment: Please read and follow the
[Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's really pretty simple...

```
nodes_permutation nP=new nodes_permutation();
     for(int i=0;i<Permutation_S.size();i++)
    {
         for(int j=0;j<Permutation_S.get(i).size();j++)
         {
             Node.selectNone(nodes);
             Point p = nP.get_coordinates((Integer) Permutation_S.get(i).get(j));
```

You create a new `nodes_permutation` (PLEASE consider using java naming conventions!) called `nP`. However, the empty constructor of that class (so the one you're using) looks like this:

```
public nodes_permutation() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

Meaning absolutely nothing happens. Especially, the variables

```
int node_value;
Point node_loc;
String node_label;
```

all stay `null` (well except `node_value`, which will be `0`).

So when you call

```
public Point get_coordinates(int n_v)
{
    return this.node_loc;
}
```

`this.node_loc` is `null` and hence you return `null`. Also, as someone already mentioned in the comments: You never use `n_v`, so you should reconsider even keeping that parameter.

Comment: So, How can I change it, So it doesn't return null?

Comment: That very much depends on what you want to achieve. But generally, doing something like `node_loc = somethingotherthannull` at some point that's actually being executed tends to help.